# Cancel a running coroutine and initiate a new with every mouse click in Kotlin.

Tags: javafx, concurrency, kotlin, coroutine

Note that I am using the javafx library. Below is a function from a class Ship that moves through space. the player clicks on the ship, a drop-down menu appears and upon clicking "move" a coroutine is started \moveJob\ that calls the function \move()\ which will make the object start moving towards its destination.

The problem is that if I click on "move" once more, mid-voyage, then the object will behave erratically since two coroutines would be running at the same time and updating the x and y coordinates of the object.

Therefore I need to cancel \moveJob\ everytime I click on "move" and start a new coroutine with a new destination. I just haven't figured out how I can use \movingJob.cancel()\ preemptively so to say, in case there is one coroutine already running.

```
item1.setOnAction {

        println("Something...")
        root.onMouseClicked = EventHandler { event ->
            launch {
                println("Clicked on an object.")
            }
            /* If you click on an object, you don't want scene.onMouseClicked
                to be executed. event.consume() gobbles the event so that it isn't passed
                down.
             */
            event.consume()
            // Here we should have something that reaches
            root.onMouseClicked = null
            scene.onMouseClicked = null
        }
        scene.onMouseClicked = EventHandler { event ->
            val moveJob =launch {
                move(event, root)
            }
            root.onMouseClicked = null
            scene.onMouseClicked = null
        }

        /* Move to coorindates that the user clicks next */
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Declare `Job` variable somewhere in your class

```
private var currentJob: Job? = null
```

And use following code

```
item1.setOnAction {
    println("Something...")
    root.onMouseClicked = EventHandler { event ->
        currentJob?.cancel()
        currentJob = launch {
            println("Clicked on an object.")
        }
        /* If you click on an object, you don't want scene.onMouseClicked
            to be executed. event.consume() gobbles the event so that it isn't passed
            down.
         */
        event.consume()
        // Here we should have something that reaches
        root.onMouseClicked = null
        scene.onMouseClicked = null
    }
    scene.onMouseClicked = EventHandler { event ->
        currentJob?.cancel()
        currentJob = launch {
            move(event, root)
        }
        root.onMouseClicked = null
        scene.onMouseClicked = null
    }

    /* Move to coorindates that the user clicks next */
}
```

Comment: it worked. However, I had to create an empty job private var currentJob: Job = Job() 
otherwise I wasn't able to use job.isActive in an if-statement